# Finding a Diagonal Matrix for a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

here is the problem:

[image]

I am pretty stuck on this one. I thought that the formula for a projection was: 
w*x/w*w times w, which in turn forms a matrix [w1^2, w1w2], [w1w1, w2^2] * 1/ (w1^2 + w2^2), but when I plug in the values w1 =1 and w2 = 2 I get [1 2], [2, 4] * (1/3), which is no the matrix that given in the solution: [1, 2], [-2,1].

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that you got the wrong value for $w_1^2+w_2^2$, the problem is that you’re only half done. You’ve found a matrix for $T$, but relative to the standard basis. The problem asks you to find a basis for which this matrix is diagonal. It’s an orthogonal projection, so the eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$ (check this yourself) and you should be able to figure out the corresponding eigenvectors without having to solve any equations. *Hint:* What does this projection do to the line $k[1,2]^T$ and what is its kernel?

*Update:* In this two-dimensional case, you can think of the projection $T$ as breaking a vector down into two components: one parallel to $[1,2]^T$ and one perpendicular to it. The parallel component is unchanged by $T$, but the perpendicular one gets mapped to $0$, so is in $\ker T$.

This is just like the situation in the standard basis: you have a component parallel to the $x$-axis and one perpendicular to it. If you project orthogonally onto the $x$-axis, the $x$-component of the vector remains unchanged, but the $y$-component becomes $0$. The matrix of this projection onto the $x$-axis (relative to the standard basis) is obviously $$M=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.$$ So, for the transformation $T$, if you take $[1,2]^T$ and some vector perpendicular to it, such as $[-2,1]^T$, as a basis, the matrix of $T$ relative to that basis will also be $M$. The change-of-basis matrix that maps from this basis back to the standard one will, of course, have these two vectors as its columns.

This leads to one way to motivate the idea of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, by the way: we ask what lines (planes, &c) are mapped to themselves by a linear transformation. That is, can we find a non-zero vector $\mathbf v$ and a scalar $\lambda$ such that $T\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$?

Comment: We haven't learned anything about eigenvalues yet, just change of basis. The kernel of 1,2 would be <-2, 1> (for example), like they give. But is there some interpretation outside of using eigenvalues why the matrix consists of a line parallel and a line perpendicular to the L given in the problem? -thanks!

Comment: @BNA See the additions to my answer.